# EX_BAD_ACCESS when calling vector.empty()

Tags: c++

I'm getting a `EX_BAD_ACCESS` when calling `vector.empty` on an empty vector.

```
bool empty = elements.empty();
```

Its throwing the exception here;

```
      /**
       *  Returns a read-only (constant) iterator that points one past
       *  the last element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in
       *  ordinary element order.
       */
      const_iterator
      end() const
      { return const_iterator(this->_M_impl._M_finish); } // EXCEPTION
```

when calling;

```
  /**
   *  Returns true if the %vector is empty.  (Thus begin() would
   *  equal end().)
   */
  bool
  empty() const
  { return begin() == end(); } // EXCEPTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that `elements` is an invalid object at that point. You should never get this exception for a valid vector object.

Answer (score 2):

As @microtherion stated, elements is most likely an invalid object.  A simple way this this can happen:

```
std::vector<MyType> *theElements = nullptr;
std::vector<MyType> &elements = *theElements;
bool empty = elements.empty();
```

Or by returning a vector reference that is a temporary object and dies when it goes out of scope at the end of the function:

```
std::vector<MyType>& GetElements() {
  std::vector<MyType> temporaryElements;
  //add to vector here.
  return temporaryElements;
}

void foo() {
  std::vector<MyType> &elements = GetElements();
  bool empty = elements.empty();
}
```

Or by holding a reference to a member variable of another class that gets cleaned up before:

```
class Foo {
  private: std::vector<MyType> mElements;
  public: std::vector<MyType>& GetElements();
};

class Bar {
private:
  std::vector<MyType>& elements;
public:
  Bar(Foo& foo) : elements(foo.GetElements()) { }

  void Do(void) { bool empty = elements.empty(); }
};

//Probably much more hidden between multiple function calls, rather than this clear example.
void func(void) {
  Bar* bar = nullptr;
  {
    Foo foo;
    bar = new Bar(foo);
    //foo dies, and so does the elements vector bar.elements refers to.
  }

  bar->Do();
  delete bar;
}
```